# Tightness of the empirical mean of an i.i.d. sequence with infinite variance.

Tags: probability

I have a question concerning the behavior of the empirical mean, any help would be appreciated !

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables such that $E(X_1) = 0$. Whitout any further assumption, do we still have that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is bounded in probability ?

Comment: By “bounded in probability” do you mean that $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded (uniformly in $n$) almost surely or...?

Comment: What i mean is this : a sequence $(Z_n)_n$ is bounded in probability if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that $P(Z_n > K_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$ for all $n$